# Send mail to outlook groups

Tags: c#, winforms, sendmail

I am sending mail to individuals in my organisation using SendMail() function of MailMessage class.My company is using outlook for mails. In outlook one can add individuals in an outlook group.

Is it possible to send mail to an outlook group directly using MailMessage class or is Interop outlook is required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to use the interop because that group is specific to that person's outlook install or global settings on the email server like Exchange. If the mail group was an alias on the receiving mail server then you would just send to that group as if it were an email, IE. Managers@mycompany.com.

Comment: I ma getting error following error when I use MailMessage Class:  Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

GROUPNAME <mailto:GROUPNAME@COMPANY.com> 
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to use the interop to send emoil through outlook on behalf of the user or use the user's SMTP credentials then. This is a security issue and not how to send emails to a group. Do other emails go through no problem; not ones to that specific group?

Comment: Ya,its working ;I tried it using credentials and its working now.I used NetworkCredential class and supplied credentials in the parameters. Thanks for the suggestion. No need to use Outlook Interop.